# get_extra_restriction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'related_alias' error django

Tags: django, django-taggit, django-errors, django-tagging

I deployed my django site on heroku and when i run my url which uses django taggit in it error shows up. I am using django taggit for meta keys to find related blogs.

Comment: Are you using Django 4.0?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Django 4.0, there was an [issue](https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit/issues/776) at `django-taggit`. They have already fixed it, you should try to upgrade your package:

```
pip install django-taggit --upgrade
```

If this does not work, you can also try install actual version from git like this:

```
pip uninstall django-taggit
pip install git+https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit.git@d0833966d357ed1e1b9b1f40c39c1ed99affbf9b
```

Comment: it does not work:( but thanks

Comment: I updated the answer, you can try one more option. If this does not work too, you should give us more information about your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work for me. I posted the answer.

Comment: The second solution worked for me. I just changed the install line into "pip install git+https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit.git@master"

Answer (score 1):

problem was the version of the django. From now i am using Django==3.2.5, and everything works fine.